# Unhandled Exception in TcpClient with Xamarin.Android Visual Studio 2010

Tags: android, tcpclient

I need help on socket programming for android device. I am a novice in `Xamarin.Android` programming but not a novice in .NET programming. I want to implement an application which communicates with remote server using socket. I know i could do this using TCPClient in c# .NET, but when I try to do this using TCPClient in `Xamarin.Android`, I got a runtime error, No debug error, No build error, but I got an `Unhandled Exception` which crashes my application at runtime.

Visual Studio and ´Xamarin.Android`did not provide any detail about this error, all I saw was`Unhandled Exception`. I am connecting to a local WAMP server running on my PC.

NOTE: If I do this using c# only (c# console app) without `Xamarin.Android`, everything works fine, but when it gets to android project using c# with xamarin, I got this error. I am confused and don't know what to do.

The line of code that gives the error is:

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient cl = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 80);
```

I am using visual studio 2010 with Xamarin.Android. Pls help.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After a lot of troubleshooting, i managed to get a little detail about the error. The detail says:

UNHANDELED EXCEPTION: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Maybe the details of the error might help in providing solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found out the solution. The problem arise because i am trying to connect to localhost i.e 127.0.0.1 which is pointing to the simulator and not the developing machine, when i change 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 everything works fine.

Thanks all for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the permission to access networking resources in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This allows your application network access.

Hope this helps.